# Python: Can the function dropna (pandas dataframe) drop rows with blank cells?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I drop rows with blank cell?

```
dftest
Out[284]: 
             aaa    aaa_f  aaa_rw    test
Period                                       
19931115  26.853  26.9142  26.873  26.873
19931116  26.861  26.8453  26.853  26.853
19931117  26.903  26.8528  26.861  26.861
19931118  26.880           26.903  26.903
19931119  26.881           26.880  26.880
19931122  26.900           26.881  26.881
19931123  26.899           26.900  26.900
```

This does not work if I call the function dropna() directly

```
dftest.dropna()
Out[285]: 
             aaa    aaa_f  aaa_rw    test
Period                                       
19931115  26.853  26.9142  26.873  26.873
19931116  26.861  26.8453  26.853  26.853
19931117  26.903  26.8528  26.861  26.861
19931118  26.880           26.903  26.903
19931119  26.881           26.880  26.880
19931122  26.900           26.881  26.881
19931123  26.899           26.900  26.900
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.replace` and `dropna`:

```
df.replace("", np.nan).dropna()
```

Output:

```
     Period     aaa    aaa_f  aaa_rw    test
0  19931115  26.853  26.9142  26.873  26.873
1  19931116  26.861  26.8453  26.853  26.853
2  19931117  26.903  26.8528  26.861  26.861
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass `how='any'`, which drops all rows with any nan cells.

```
df.dropna(how='any')
```

Output:

```
             aaa    aaa_f  aaa_rw    test
Period                                   
19931115  26.853  26.9142  26.873  26.873
19931116  26.861  26.8453  26.853  26.853
19931117  26.903  26.8528  26.861  26.861
```

If you only want to drop those `nan` in a specific columns, you can pass `subset` instead:

```
df.dropna(subset=['aaa_f'])
```

---

**Update:** It occurs to me that your column might be string type and the blank values mean the empty string `''`, so you want

```
df[df['aaa_f'].ne('')]
```

or

```
df[df.ne('').all(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. dftest.dropna(how='any')
Out[291]: 
             twd    twd_f  twd_rw    test
Period                                       
19931115  26.853  26.9142  26.873  26.873
19931116  26.861  26.8453  26.853  26.853
19931117  26.903  26.8528  26.861  26.861
19931118  26.880           26.903  26.903
19931119  26.881           26.880  26.880
19931122  26.900           26.881  26.881
19931123  26.899           26.900  26.900

Comment: Is your blank cell the `NaN` or the string `''`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `inplace` option,

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

or reassign your `df`

```
df = df.dropna()
```